# No cellular data after update

Tags: ubuntu-touch, 3g

I updated my BQ Aquaris saturday, and since then I have no cellular data anymore. WIFI works fine.

I checked my APN settings, and they seem empty, I tried to change to custom settings and manually set the APN to my provider (internet.proximus.be) but that doesn't work. Before the update my APN was automatically right.

The icon in the upper bar shows that the phone IS connected to HSDPA.

How do I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: If you install the terminal app (or use adb shell while the phone is connected by USB and developer mode is ON), you can inspect APNs using the script `/usr/share/ofono/scripts/list-contexts`. Confirm that the settings match the ones provided by your mobile network operator. If not, you can remove the contexts altogether with `/usr/share/ofono/scripts/remove-contexts` and reboot the phone. This will give you the default settings. The APN screen is under heavy development. Thank you for this report, and for your patience. We're eager to help over at [#ubuntu-touch](http://goo.gl/cg4Kll), btw.

Comment: the remove-contexts script workd. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JonasG.Drange Please write your comments as an answer so that others can vote it up.